# Security in GCM Upstream messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My question is:

when i am implementing GCM upstream messaging. If anyone got sender id from apk, then he/she can send wrong data or send data after modify. How can GCM server identify it internally???

Comment: Maybe you can send your data encrypted from your "backend" and decrypted at the reciver to add an aditional security factor

Comment: i want to know how GCM work internally when received data from android device to send our app server.

Comment: Your mistake its to think one device sends a GCM to another, your sender id should be stored in your server, your client should ask the server to send the GCM to the other device.

Comment: Hi Boss, i am not getting exactly what are you saying. can you please explain in detail with example??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way GCM can tell if the client has tampered with upstream message.